# Run vb.net code directly from cmd or Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

I'm starting to code with vb.net and i need to run the code directly, like it happens with java: in the cmd i can run the class files. Is there any similar possibility with vb.net, preferably directly from the visual studio hub?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember to mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted by pressing the check mark on the left of it. -- Since you're new here, please also take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Hi; If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [**Immediate Window**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) for that. It offers many different ways to interact with your code. To use it, start your application in debug mode from Visual Studio and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

To execute a shared method you can type in the Immediate Window:

```
className.methodName()

(example)
MainFunctions.DoStuff()
DoMoreStuff()
```

- Where `className` is optional if you're currently already inside the class (for example if you've hit a breakpoint in it).

If you want to execute an instance (non-shared) method you can either use the method above (without `className`, but you must currently be inside the class by hitting a breakpoint, for example), or you create a new instance of the class and execute the method:

```
Public Class MiscFunctions
    Public Sub PrintHelloWorld()
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello World!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
(Immediate Window)
New MiscFunctions().PrintHelloWorld()
Hello World!

Dim m As New MiscFunctions
m.PrintHelloWorld()
Hello World!
```

You can also print the value of a variable or the return value of a function by typing:

```
? variableOrFunctionNameHere

(example)
? ImageCount
4
```

The same rules for executing methods applies to evaluating functions too:

```
Public Class MiscFunctions
    Public Shared Function IsEven(ByVal Num As Integer) As Boolean
        Return Num Mod 2 = 0
    End Function

    Public Function Sum(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer 'Non-shared method.
        Return a + b
    End Function
End Class
```

```
(Immediate Window)
? MiscFunctions.IsEven(3)
False
? MiscFunctions.IsEven(8)
True
? New MiscFunctions().Sum(3, 9)
12
```

You can also dynamically evaluate expressions:

```
? ImageCount + 1 = 5 'Here, ImageCount is 4
True
? 2 * 4
8
```

Comment: Nice answer - I am not sure how I never saw it before you linked to it.

Comment: Oh - posted XMas day - that explains it, you pagan.  ;)

Comment: @Plutonix : Thanks! Though I'm not a pagan, in Sweden we celebrate Christmas on the 24th. ;)

Comment: @Plutonix : However I couldn't have skipped visiting Stack Overflow on Christmas, for then I wouldn't [**have been here for a year**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfbnL.png). :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for more then the Immediate Window. Look into Microsoft CodeDom. I have used it to compile C#, VB.net, C++, and Visual J#.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Though CodeDom must be executed inside the code itself. The OP is looking for a way to execute methods dynamically from the development environment, without altering the actual code.